# Simplest way to parse a Date in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to parse a Date chosen by user:

```
var ds = "11 / 08 / 2009";
```

I use

```
var d = new Date(ds);
```

It gives me November, 08, 2009. But what I need is August, 11, 2009.

What is the simplest way to parse the date?

Comment: Are dates always going to be in DD/MM/YYYY format?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are lots of libraries and copy-and-paste javascript snippets on the net for this kind of thing, but here is one more.

```
function dateParse(s) {
  var parts = s.split('/');
  var d = new Date( parts[2], parts[1]-1, parts[0]);
  return d;
}
```

Comment: ¨Because JS' Date's month is a 0-based index for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

I have had success with [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/). In particular, you would want to use [parseExact](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#parseExact), which allows you to provide a format string describing the meaning of each segment (so that you can map one segment to day and another to month).

Answer (score 1):

Extend date to return values in your desired format.

[Here](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Javascript_Dates-The_Complete_Reference) is a great article on how to do so. It includes code snippets.