# JavaScript won't parse GMT Date/Time Format

Tags: javascript, datetime, date

I'm trying to get JavaScript to parse a date and time format for me, with the eventual aim of telling me the days passed since that date and the time right now (locally).

Unfortunately, the date format I have to work with (it's from a JSON response which I don't have control over) is returning it in 2008-10-01 06:21:43 type format.

```
var thedate = "2008-10-01 06:21:43";
var inmillisecs = new Date(thedate);
```

This just returns an error from JavaScript telling me the date is invalid.

How do I get around this issue?

Comment: Shouldn't the parameter to new Date be thedate?

Answer (score 8):

This should do it

```
function dateFromUTC( dateAsString, ymdDelimiter )
{
  var pattern = new RegExp( "(\\d{4})" + ymdDelimiter + "(\\d{2})" + ymdDelimiter + "(\\d{2}) (\\d{2}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2})" );
  var parts = dateAsString.match( pattern );

  return new Date( Date.UTC(
      parseInt( parts[1] )
    , parseInt( parts[2], 10 ) - 1
    , parseInt( parts[3], 10 )
    , parseInt( parts[4], 10 )
    , parseInt( parts[5], 10 )
    , parseInt( parts[6], 10 )
    , 0
  ));
}

alert( dateFromUTC( "2008-10-01 06:21:43", '-' ) );
```

Comment: Thanks... this was a great start!  I wanted local (not UTC) time, so I ended up changing the parts[5] line to: "       , parseInt( parts[5], 10 ) - new Date().getTimezoneOffset() ".  There are caveats, but I'm willing to live with them... see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263705/display-local-time-from-utc-time-stored-in-sql-database-on-asp-net-app

Answer (score 3):

There's this nice looking library called [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/). I have no experience with it, but you might find it useful. I think you'd be particularly interested in `parse()` and/or `parseExact()`.

I originally heard about it from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258310/simplest-way-to-parse-a-date-in-javascript).

Cheers.

EDIT: I just noticed your mention of time and I'm not sure DateJS handles times so I'm going to look into that real quick, or else you can just ignore this post :)

Comment: DateJS doesn't look like it is being developed anymore (last update was in 2008). Instead, try http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 2):

The expected format is the American format: `m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss`

```
var date1 = new Date("2008-10-01 06:21:43"); //fails
var date2 = new Date("10/1/2008 06:21:43"); //works correctly
```

Comment: thanks for clarifying this Kip - unfortunately, as stated, I don't have control over the format since it's coming from an API via JSON.

I guess the only option I have is to regex replace everything, woopee.

Comment: @Jake: this answer might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274743/how-can-i-determine-a-timezone-by-the-utc-offset/1274752#1274752

Comment: Sadly, no, the spec isn't even that specific. All it basically says is that new Date(string) should be able to parse whatever someDate.toString() spits out, which is implementation-dependent. http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm

Comment: @Jake: Yup, looks like that's your best option, and then use the long form of the Date constructor that takes the parts individually.  Still, the regex isn't that bad...

Comment: The spec, such as it is, *does* say that the RFC822-style date format ‘Mon, 25 Dec 1995 13:30:00 GMT’ is supported. This is at least better than the US-style format with no timezone, though it is still pretty woeful. This sort of insanity is why it's generally best to deal with timestamps as integers (eg. in Unix-style seconds-since-epoch) whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

That's an ISO 9601 date -- they're a nice standard to work with. Try just munging it using regular expressions:

```
(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})[ tT](.*)
```

to

```
\2/\3/\1 \4
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax should be:

```
    var thedate = "Oct 1, 2008 06:21:43";
    var inmillisecs = new Date(thedate);
```

You have to take some steps to transform the String you're receiving into the format I showed. Using the american format also works

```
   var thedate = "10/1/2008 06:21:42";
   var inmillisecs = new Date(thedate);
```

Answer (score 0):

it must be a string that is recognizable by the parse() function.

http://www.devguru.com/technologies/javascript/10585.asp look at the dateString param