# Convert date from string in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, date

i need to convert from a date in string format like this "2011-05-12 16:50:44.055" to the number of milliseconds since midnight 1 January 1970 date format in Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure correct cross-browser behaviour, I think you should parse the string yourself. I moulded [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308720/javascript-wont-parse-gmt-date-time-format/1308824#1308824) into:

```
function msFromString(dateAsString)
{
    var parts = dateAsString.match(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}).(\d{3})/);

    return new Date(parts[1],
                    parts[2] - 1,
                    parts[3],
                    parts[4],
                    parts[5],
                    parts[6],
                    parts[7]).getTime();
}

console.log(msFromString("2011-05-12 16:50:44.055"));
```

This outputs `1305211844055`.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE 2023

The failure is up to the browser implementation's handling of [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) and how they allow for date strings not conform the [date standards](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format)

> ECMAScript defines a string interchange format for date-times based upon a simplification of the ISO 8601 calendar date extended format.
> The format is as follows: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`

So we can force your string into this

```js
const getDateFromString = str => {
  const [date,time] = str.split(" ");
  // reformat string into YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ
  str = `${date}T${time}Z`
  return new Date(str);
};
let date = getDateFromString('2011-05-12 16:50:44.055');
console.log(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `Date.parse()` method? It should recognise this format (though I haven't tested that). The return value should be the number of milliseconds since 01/01/1970.

Comment: It is specified that `Date.parse` only needs to accept string formatted according to [RFC 1123](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1123), all other formats are browser-dependent, so you can't rely on it in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Make a Date object from the date string and use the getTime() method to get the milliseconds since 1 January 1970. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

```
var date = new Date("2011-05-12 16:50:44.055");
document.write(date.getTime());
```