# How to combine date time string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have following date and time string.

```
var myDateString = '17-05-2019 10:30 PM';
```

How can I convert it to a javascript date? I have tried to find on Google but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356519/convert-date-from-string-in-javascript

Comment: you can use native js date `new Date(myDateString);` or use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Please follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308720/javascript-wont-parse-gmt-date-time-format/1308824#1308824

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the native js library.

`new Date(myDateString)`

Comment: It's working for me. I changed the date format to yyyy-mm-dd then combined the time 10:30 PM and its working fine.