# How to sort div's by content date

Tags: jquery, sorting, date, html

I'm trying to sort div's by content date... 
What i've got is sorting. But not by date...

HTML

```
 <div id="all_elements">

            <!-- one element -->
            <div class="element">
                    <div class="display-number">02</div>
                    <div class="year">20-10-2011</div>
            </div><!-- element -->

            <!-- one element -->
            <div class="element">
                    <div class="display-number">03</div>
                    <div class="year">22-09-2011</div>
            </div><!-- element -->

            <!-- one element -->
            <div class="element">
                    <div class="display-number">01</div>
                    <div class="year">01-12-2011</div>
            </div><!-- element -->

            <!-- one element -->
            <div class="element">
                    <div class="display-number">04</div>
                    <div class="year">01-06-2011</div>
            </div><!-- element -->

            <!-- one element -->
            <div class="element">
                    <div class="display-number">05</div>
                    <div class="year">01-06-2010</div>
            </div><!-- element -->

        </div> <!--all_elements-->
```

JQUERY

```
<script>
        function sortDescending(a, b) {
            return $(a).find(".year").text() < $(b).find(".year").text() ? 1 : -1;
        };
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#all_elements .element').sort(sortDescending).appendTo('#all_elements');
        }); 
    </script>
```

I know i need a function to figure out the content is a date.. 
Just don't know how...

Who can help me out?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308720/javascript-wont-parse-gmt-date-time-format Javascript is not very lenient on date formats.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could do:

```
   function sortDescending(a, b) {
     var date1  = $(a).find(".year").text();
       date1 = date1.split('-');
     date1 = new Date(date1[2], date1[1] -1, date1[0]);
     var date2  = $(b).find(".year").text();
       date2= date2.split('-');
     date2= new Date(date2[2], date2[1] -1, date2[0]);

     return date1 < date2 ? 1 : -1;
    };
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#all_elements .element').sort(sortDescending).appendTo('#all_elements');
    });
```

EDIT - corrected the typo according to the comment! Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/TsZeg/

Comment: +1, I made this for you: http://jsfiddle.net/TsZeg/ and you have a typo in the second date $(b) not $(a)

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle and for spotting the typo! :)

Comment: What would have to change to also support date and time?

Comment: Sorry the answer is simple just ad the time to tbe new dates duh

Comment: To sort ascending use return date1 > date2 ? 1 : -1;

Answer (score 0):

did you try the date object: `new Date($('.year').text())`?

Comment: Well, yes, if your computer knows you're dealing with non-US date formats.

Comment: exactly; you have to shoehorn it in.

Answer (score 0):

Use my jquery plugin SortContent :

```
$('#all_elements').sortContent({asc:true})
```

But , as your sort a based on something distinct of String (Date) , you should use `format` callback. 
And, As the Date is not the whole HTML of elements to sort , you should use `helper` callback to identify the suitable content.

```
$('div#all_elements').sortContent({format:parser,helper:myhelper})
```

**Required callbacks :**

```
parser=function(content){
    content=content.split('-');
    //Convert 20-10-2011 to 10/20/2011 to be ready to Date parsing
    content=content[1]+'/'+content[0]+'/'+content[2]
    return Date.parse(content)
};
myhelper=function(e){
   return $('.year',$(e)).html();
}
```

DEMO :

http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/E4Hbp/8/