# Sort element positions by date

Tags: jquery, date, sorting, position

Anyone can give me some how to sort element positions by date ?

**Exmample HTML :**

```
<div class="side left">
    <div class="box" data-date="06/29/2013"></div>
    <div class="box" data-date="06/29/2013"></div>
    <div class="box" data-date="06/30/2013"></div>
</div>

<div class="side right">
    <div class="box" data-date="06/28/2013"></div>
    <div class="box" data-date="06/30/2013"></div>
</div>
```

I want to sort boxes by date, Who newer will go lower to bottom position than newer. (If you understand)

I made some demo in GIF like this...

[image: Sort element positions by date]

**I dont some part with this now :**

```
$('.side .box').each(function(i){
        var box = $(this);
        var date = $(this).data('date');
        var format_date = new Date(date);
        var top = parseInt(box.offset().top);
        // HERE WE GO !!!

});
```

Now I have no idea how to do , Can someone help me or give some idea ?

**Playground + Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/b2Wx5/

---

**Okey : I come to this step now , Any can review it ?**

http://jsfiddle.net/b2Wx5/7/

Any ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use this plugin  http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/. 
Add some changes in `sortElements` to consider date.
Something like

```
  var date1 = // pass date from first elemnt ;
  date1 = date1.split('/');
  date1 = //pass date from second element;
  var date2 = $(b).find(".date").text();
  date2 = date2.split('/');
  date2 = new Date(date2[2], date2[1] - 1, date2[0]);
  return date1 < date2 ? 1 : -1;
```

Got similar question [How to sort div's by content date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742090/how-to-sort-divs-by-content-date). By adding few changes to it, you can use the same with your sceanrio

Comment: i dont undertstand `pass date from first element`.. `pass date from second element`...

Comment: I try this http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/ , but it looke like sorter by normal one col. But what about 2 cols ? http://jsfiddle.net/b2Wx5/1/