# Order divs by date content

Tags: jquery, html, sorting

I have the following function I am using to sort my array of divs by date -

```
function sortDates(arrayContent) {
    arrayContent.sort(function (a, b) {

        var arrDate = $(a).find("#postedDate").text().replace(" posted at: ", "");
        var brrDate = $(b).find("#postedDate").text().replace(" posted at: ", "");

        var aTime = arrDate.split(' ')[1];
        var aDate = arrDate.split(' ')[0];
        a = new Date(aDate.split('/')[2], aDate.split('/')[1] - 1, aDate.split('/')[0], aTime.split(':')[0], aTime.split(':')[1]);

        var bTime = brrDate.split(' ')[1];
        var bDate = brrDate.split(' ')[0];
        b = new Date(bDate.split('/')[2], bDate.split('/')[1] - 1, bDate.split('/')[0], bTime.split(':')[0], bTime.split(':')[1]);

        return a > b ? -1 : a < b ? 1 : 0;
    });
}
```

Where `arrayContent` =

```
arrayContent[0] = "<div class="mHr" id="mFID"> 
   <div id="postedDate"> posted at: <b>11/12/2015 11:12:16</b> </div>
</div>" // etc etc
```

This current function does work however I am looking to sort hundreds of divs and the runtime using this method is taking forever.

Current limitations are that I cannot do a date converstion before populating `arrayContent` and each value added to `arrayContent` is always a string of HTML, hence why I have to find the `postedDate` and then split it accordingly to create a valid date variable.

This is the best I have come up with and it works however as previously mentioned it is super slow.

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742090/how-to-sort-divs-by-content-date) question which is doing much the same as me however no faster solution.

Comment: That's a server-side task. If you don't want to crash the client browsers.

Comment: Where is the data for this array coming from in the first place and can you not sort it there?

Comment: @Rob C it is coming from api calls, multiple ones with different formats that the data gets parsed out of and creates the generic HTML arrayContent values.

Comment: Ok. I think the best idea would be to write a server side service which consumes these APIs, collates and sorts the data, then serve up the processed content to the client.

Comment: yes that is what I was thinking, I guess it makes sense when dealing with much larger volumes in production, worked well for a demo though! :)

Comment: `$(a).find("#postedDate")` Ids have to be unique

Comment: Indeed :) Good luck @Ebikeneser

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with hundreds of elements that is a server task. But only for test purposes, try this little sort function, it avoids the use of jQuery, avoid split methods, avoid Date class and uses regular expressions to compare two numbers instead. I've tried with a one hundred items array and it takes 29.570ms and the original function takes 996.119ms.

```
var reg = /^.*?(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})\s(\d{2})\:(\d{2})\:(\d{2}).*$/;

function sortDates(a, b){   

  var numberA = Number( a.replace(reg, "$3$2$1$4$5$6") );
  var numberB = Number( b.replace(reg, "$3$2$1$4$5$6") );

  return numberA - numberB;

}

arrayContent.sort(sortDates);
```