# sort divs based on dates - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have divs with data attribute `data-submit-date` and i want to sort them based on the value of this attribute which is date format.

here's the code for one of the divs:

```
<div class="article" data-submit-date="2017-09-12T05:45:36.951Z">
     <h1>aaaaA</h1>
</div>
```

my attempts:

```
$divss = $(".article");
    var alphaOrderDivs = $divss.sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(a).data("submit-date") > $(b).data("submit-date"); 
});
$(".articles").html(alphaOrderDivs);
```

I replaced this line `$(a).data("submit-date")` with `Date.parse($(a).data("submit-date"))` but it fails. Can anyone help me?

Thank In Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort div's by content date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742090/how-to-sort-divs-by-content-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
var articles = $.makeArray($(".article"));
articles.sort(function(a, b) {
   return new Date($(a).data("submit-date")) < new Date($(b).data("submit-date"));
});
```

Snippet

```js
var articles = $.makeArray($(".article"));
    articles.sort(function(a, b) {
       return new Date($(a).data("submit-date")) < new Date($(b).data("submit-date"));
    });
    console.log(articles);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="article" data-submit-date="2017-09-10T05:45:36.951Z">
     <h1>aaaaA</h1>
</div>
<div class="article" data-submit-date="2017-09-12T05:45:36.951Z">
     <h1>aaaaA</h1>
</div>
<div class="article" data-submit-date="2017-09-11T05:45:36.951Z">
     <h1>aaaaA</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the getTime() method as follows:

```
 $divss = $(".article");
 var alphaOrderDivs = $divss.sort(function (a, b) {
   return new Date($(a).data("submit-date")).getTime() > new Date($(b).data("submit-date")).getTime(); 
 });
 $(".articles").html(alphaOrderDivs);
```

The getTime() method of the Date object will parse your time into milliseconds and will hence help you compare them.

Comment: Yes you can compare Date objects