# sorting divs by date specific

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to sort divs by a specific date or by two dates

Example:

if **i taped** 27-09-2018 **I posted from 27-09-2018**

**this my code**

1-I created a function who compared between date and input
2-after compare i display the chosen date

```js
function sortDescending(a, b) {
  

  var date1 = $("#datepick").val();
 

    date1 = new Date(date1[0], date1[1] - 1, date1[2]);
    var date2 = $(b).find(".year").text();
    date2 = date2.split('-');
   date2 = new Date(date2[2], date2[1] - 1, date2[0]);

    return date1 >= date2;
};
$('#datepick').click(function () {
console.log("tt");
    $('#all_elements .element').sort(sortDescending).appendTo('#all_elements');
});
```

```html
<input type="date" id="datepick"/>
<div id="all_elements">
    
    <!-- one element -->
    <div class="element">
        <div class="display-number">02</div>
        <div class="year">20-10-2011</div>
    </div><!-- element -->
    
    <!-- one element -->
    <div class="element">
        <div class="display-number">03</div>
        <div class="year">22-09-2011</div>
    </div><!-- element -->
    
    <!-- one element -->
    <div class="element">
        <div class="display-number">01</div>
        <div class="year">01-12-2011</div>
    </div><!-- element -->
    
    <!-- one element -->
    <div class="element">
        <div class="display-number">04</div>
        <div class="year">01-06-2011</div>
    </div><!-- element -->
    
    <!-- one element -->
    <div class="element">
        <div class="display-number">05</div>
        <div class="year">29-09-2019</div>
    </div><!-- element -->
    
</div> <!--all_elements--
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742090/how-to-sort-divs-by-content-date

Comment: yes already I took the same code and i changed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort div's by content date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742090/how-to-sort-divs-by-content-date)

Comment: i duplicate but not works

Comment: any solution for this case