# How to create date in YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to create the date in YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format using JavaScript ? For example, I want to get the date as 20131018064838.

Comment: I would use the library I suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734032/date-format-convert-javascript/17734119#17734119) anyway it would help a lot if you share your actual code too.

Comment: (new Date()).toISOString().replace(/[^0-9]/g, "").slice(0, -3)

Comment: @MBS yours is the aptest answer

Comment: another solution: `dt=new Date().toISOString().split('.')[0].replace(/[^\d]/gi,'');` sets `dt` to, (for example): `20210809154700`

Comment: Or `new Date.toISOString().replace(/(\.\d{3})|[^\d]/g,'')`

Comment: With https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format , `timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")(yourDate)`

Answer (score 21):

```
var date = new Date();

alert( date.getFullYear() + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + ("0" + date.getHours() ).slice(-2) + ("0" + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ("0" + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2) );
```

edit

```
function pad2(n) { return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n }

var date = new Date();
    
alert( date.getFullYear().toString() + pad2(date.getMonth() + 1) + pad2( date.getDate()) + pad2( date.getHours() ) + pad2( date.getMinutes() ) + pad2( date.getSeconds() ) );
```

Comment: neat as the `('0' + n).slice(-2)` hack is, IMHO it's not very readable and the OP would be far better served with a little `pad2` helper function, e.g. `function pad2(n) { return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n }`

Comment: p.s. and why +1 the `getHours` result?!

Comment: Halfway through line 2 you started using `this` instead of `date`.

Comment: @Butt4cak3 made changes as per suggestions

Comment: @gurvinder372 congrats - you now have the only correct (standalone) answer!

Comment: @Alnitak thanks for your suggestions & corrections

Comment: @gurvinder372 actually there's one further change required - at least _one_ of the fields (suggest the `year` field) needs to be forced into a string to ensure that you get string concatenation instead of addition.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
The above message is coming

Comment: @RaheebM: missing `)` just before, I've edited it.

Comment: not working: `this.getDate is not a function`

Comment: @KevinDuke check the edit below that.

Comment: I'd do it in a one-liner like `new Date().toISOString().replace(/[^0-9]/gm, "").substr(0,14)`.

Answer (score 11):

Here's my (ES5 safe) method to add the `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS()` function to any `Date` object.

On older browsers, either shim `Object.defineProperty` or just add the inner function directly to `Date.prototype`:

```
Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'YYYYMMDDHHMMSS', {
    value: function() {
        function pad2(n) {  // always returns a string
            return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
        }

        return this.getFullYear() +
               pad2(this.getMonth() + 1) + 
               pad2(this.getDate()) +
               pad2(this.getHours()) +
               pad2(this.getMinutes()) +
               pad2(this.getSeconds());
    }
});
```

Comment: A bit subjective perhaps, but (assuming timezone being zero UTC offset is fine, ) I think `new Date().toISOString().slice(-24).replace(/\D/g,'').slice(0, 14);` is cleaner since it involves no tinkering with zero-padding or correction of the month number.

Answer (score 6):

Please try using prototype method as following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    Date.prototype.YYYYMMDDHHMMSS = function () {
        var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();
        var MM = pad(this.getMonth() + 1,2);
        var dd = pad(this.getDate(), 2);
        var hh = pad(this.getHours(), 2);
        var mm = pad(this.getMinutes(), 2)
        var ss = pad(this.getSeconds(), 2)

        return yyyy + MM + dd+  hh + mm + ss;
    };

    function getDate() {
        d = new Date();
        alert(d.YYYYMMDDHHMMSS());
    }

    function pad(number, length) {
        var str = '' + number;
        while (str.length < length) {
            str = '0' + str;
        }
        return str;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: that's a novel (but inefficient) way of zero padding the numbers...  You also omitted to zero pad the time fields.

Comment: getting better, but in this case there's no need to pad beyond two digits, and you could then make `pad2` (per the other answer that uses it) an inner function within `Date.prototype.YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` to avoid polluting the global name space.

Comment: thanks for code snippets,
I've more customized for debugging purpose.

https://jsfiddle.net/trustfarm/nvvzgax1/4/