# Javascript Date Conversion to YYYYMMDDHHMMSS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How to convert the following date format Mon Apr 16 2018 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) to 20180416190000 (YYYYMMDDHHMMSS)

Comment: Since you tagged the question [momentjs], you surely already looked at their documentation and tried something. Please post your code and tell us how it failed.

Comment: what code have you written?

Comment: `let date = new Date('Mon Apr 16 2018 19:00:00 GMT-0500'); '' + date.getFullYear() + ...`

Comment: @Bergi - The reason why I've put momentjs is that, we are using momentjs in our project, but upon looking at the documentation I didn't find any solution there. I mentioned that here, to see if anyone has a solution using momentjs.

Comment: "but upon looking at the documentation I didn't find any solution there" - you might want to look a little harder. This is pretty much moment's bread and butter.

Comment: Ok thanks, I found the solution using momentjs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create date in YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448436/how-to-create-date-in-yyyymmddhhmmss-format-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to use `moment.js` you can use the `toISOString()` method returns a string in simplified extended ISO format (ISO 8601), which is always 24 or 27 characters long (`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` or ±`YYYYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`, respectively). The timezone is always zero UTC offset, as denoted by the suffix "Z".

Then after converting the date using the method, use the `.replace()` method and use regex to format the string then use the `.slice()` method.

```
const timeStamp = (new Date()).toISOString().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').slice(0, -3)

console.log(timeStamp)
```

**Output:**
`20210928063849`

Answer (score -1):

To achieve expected result, use below option using moment.js format option

```
let date = new Date('Mon Apr 16 2018 19:00:00 GMT-0500');
console.log(moment(date).format('YYYYMMDDHHMMSS'))
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ZoEwQB?editors=1010

Comment: console.log(moment(date).format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss')), we need to put mm in lowercase so we will get minutes value otherwise we will get the month.