# Breaking down a date into segments

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simplest way to parse a Date in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258310/simplest-way-to-parse-a-date-in-javascript)

I understand how do get the data and break it down into it's segments, i.e.

```
alert( ( new Date ).getDate() );
```

and

```
alert( ( new Date ).getFullYear() );
alert( ( new Date ).getFullMonth() );
```

etc etc.

But how do I do the same but use a date from a html textbox? instead of reading `new Date`?

The date in the HTML box would be formated as follows

31/10/2012

Comment: Dates inside of html text boxes (`<input type="text">`, I guess) don't follow any specific structure.

Comment: Use string parsing functions. HOW you parse it depends entirely on how it's typed in.

Comment: I've updated the question to show how the date will be formatted in a html box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
var datearray = input.value.split("/");

var date = new Date(datearray[2],datearray[1] - 1,datearray[0])
```

Comment: I upvoted you BUT it will have to be 

    var date = new Date(datearray[2],datearray[1] - 1,datearray[0])

because month property is zero-indexed

Comment: @JohnnyLeung Thanks, that kind of leniency is rare but needed on SO

Answer (score 0):

If your textbox has proper string format for a date object you can use:

```
var aDate = new Date($("textbox").val());
```

However, if you dont write it in the text box exactly as you would in a string passing to the object, you'll get null for your variable.

FYI, I made a plugin that "extends" the Date object pretty nicely and has preformatted date/times that include things like a basic SQL datetime format.

Just go to [***this jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/frMBY/), Copy the code between `Begin Plugin` and `End Plugin` into a js file and link it in your header after your jQuery.

The use is as simple as above example:

```
var aDate = new DateTime($("textbox").val());
```

And to get a specific format from that you do:

```
var sqlDate = aDate.formats.compound.mySQL;
```