# jquery hide checkbox based on dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

developers I need a help with jQuery. I have list of checkbox and I only want certain checkbox to be displayed in page. Currently, My code displays only current date checkbox but I need more checks.  Here is what I want

- get todays todays date
- hide any checkbox options that are before todays date
- only pick 1 date which is the next possible date after today (or todays date)
- then hide all the other checkboxes

Below is my approach but feel free to help me in your own ways/code. You don't need to necessarily go with my code.

```js
$('[data-fieldlabel=\'Date and Price\'] span').each(function() {
  const date = new Date();
  const today = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear().toString().slice(-2);

  const currentDateEl = $(this).find('.check-box-label').text();

  if (!currentDateEl.startsWith(today)) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox-group" data-fieldlabel="Date and Price">
  <span class="checkbox custom-checkbox custom-check-box">
                 <input id="field_13646002_25035125" type="checkbox"/>
                 <label class="check-box-label" for="field_13646002_25035125">10/9/21 - 8.50</label>
             </span>
  <span class="checkbox custom-checkbox custom-check-box">
                <input id="field_13646002_25035126" type="checkbox"/>
                <label class="check-box-label" for="field_13646002_25035126">10/16/21 - 2.00</label>
            </span>
  <span class="checkbox custom-checkbox custom-check-box">
                <input id="field_13646002_25035126" type="checkbox"/>
                <label class="check-box-label" for="field_13646002_25035126">10/28/21 - 3.00</label>
            </span>
</div>
```

I need one more check If i don't have current date(I want to show one nearest future date) let's say today date is 10/28/21 but i have below label

```
 <label class="check-box-label" for="field_13646002_25035126">10/27/21 - 3.00</label>
  <label class="check-box-label" for="field_13646002_25035126">10/29/21 - 3.00</label>
  <label class="check-box-label" for="field_13646002_25035126">10/30/21 - 3.00</label>
```

Now I want to show only this future nearest data `<label class="check-box-label" for="field_13646002_25035126">10/29/21 - 3.00</label>`

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37505117/find-the-next-closest-date-in-mm-dd-yyy-format-javascript/37505585

Answer (score 0):

The following code may be what you need:

```js
let now=new Date();
now.setHours(0);
now.setMinutes(0);
now.setSeconds(0);
let nowTime=now.getTime();
let items=$('[data-fieldlabel=\'Date and Price\'] span');
let index=-1;
for (let i=0;i<items.length;i++){
    let theDate=($(items[i]).find('.check-box-label').text()).split(" ")[0];
  let theDateObj=new Date(theDate);
  let diff=theDateObj.getTime()-nowTime;
  if (diff>=0){
    if (index==-1){
        index=i;
      break;
    }
  }
}
for (let i=0;i<items.length;i++){
    if (i!=index){
    $(items[i]).hide();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox-group" data-fieldlabel="Date and Price">
  <span class="checkbox custom-checkbox custom-check-box">
    <input id="field_13646002_25035126" type="checkbox" />
    <label class="check-box-label" for="field_13646002_25035126">10/29/21 - 3.00</label>
  </span>
  <span class="checkbox custom-checkbox custom-check-box">
    <input id="field_13646002_25035126" type="checkbox" />
    <label class="check-box-label" for="field_13646002_25035126">10/30/21 - 3.00</label>
  </span>
  <span class="checkbox custom-checkbox custom-check-box">
    <input id="field_13646002_25035126" type="checkbox" />
    <label class="check-box-label" for="field_13646002_25035126">10/28/21 - 3.00</label>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, please it with this. I am not getting expected output
<span class="checkbox custom-checkbox custom-check-box">
        <input id="field_13646002_25035126" type="checkbox"/>
        <label class="check-box-label" for="field_13646002_25035126">10/28/21 - 3.00</label>
    </span>
    <span class="checkbox custom-checkbox custom-check-box">
        <input id="field_13646002_25035126" type="checkbox"/>
        <label class="check-box-label" for="field_13646002_25035126">10/29/21 - 3.00</label>
    </span>

Comment: if i put 10/29/21 ,10/30/21,10/28/21 together it won't; work. Based on this I should only see 10/28/21 checkbox as today's date is 10/28/21. If i don't have today's date I should only see nearest future date which is 10/29/21 if it exist other i should see next nearest data 10/30/21

Comment: You may check the following web page.
https://jsfiddle.net/2adwm0ub/

Comment: Thanks, I have checked on jsfiddle. currently it displays 10/29/21. if you remove this date it need to show nearest future date checkbox which is 10/30/21 . but it won't show. when page renders it should show 10/28/21(today's) if there is not today's , it should show one near future date

Comment: I have updated the code, please check.